# ExtJS 4 date in grid filtering delivers empty result

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I try to filter an ExtJS4 grid by date.

I have two columns that I fill like this:

```
{header: 'Start Date', width: 80, dataIndex: 'startdate', filter: { type: 'date', dateFormat: 'Y-m-d'}},
{header: 'End Date', width: 80, dataIndex: 'enddate', filter: { type: 'date', dateFormat: 'Y-m-d'}},
```

In the grid I see a the date in the right format, but the second I want to filter (before, after, on), I always get an empty result. My data store is local (no ajax) and I want to filter that locally.

Even changing it to the default Y/m/d doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Make sure that the type in the model is `date`

Answer (score 2):

Reason for this was a missing type in the model.

Before:

```
{name: 'startdate'},
{name: 'enddate'},
```

After:

```
{name: 'startdate', type: 'date'},
{name: 'enddate', type: 'date'},
```

Credits to Amensrine! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
var filter = {
    ftype: 'filters',
    encode: false,
    local: false,
    filters: [{
        // required configs
        type: 'date',
        dataIndex: 'startdate',

        // optional configs
        dateFormat: 'm/d/Y',  // default
        beforeText: 'Before', // default
        afterText: 'After',   // default
        onText: 'On',         // default
    },{
        // required configs
        type: 'date',
        dataIndex: 'enddate',

        // optional configs
        dateFormat: 'm/d/Y',  // default
        beforeText: 'Before', // default
        afterText: 'After',   // default
        onText: 'On',         // default
}]};

var Grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    id: 'Grid',
    store: store...,
    features: [ filter ],
    columns : [...]
});
```

Also you can look example here:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.ux.grid.filter.DateFilter